# WebSocket Error: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

There's this site https://www.dextools.io/ which basically displays information about different crypto coins. It also has websocket endpoint: *wss://ws.dextools.io/* that can provide real-time deals against certain coin. My goal is to connect to this endpoint via NodeJS to retrieve data about deals in real-time. I intercepted the websocket handshake request that browser sends when visiting https://www.dextools.io/ (*Inspect -> Network -> WS tab*). I tried to establish the same websocket connection via NodeJS using *ws* lib. Here's the code that I tried:

```js
import WebSocket from "ws";
import * as crypto from "crypto";

const url = "wss://ws.dextools.io";
const ws = new WebSocket(url, {
    headers: {
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Origin': 'chrome://newtab',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Sec-WebSocket-Key': crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'),
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Upgrade': 'websocket',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'Upgrade',
        'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
        'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits'
    }
});
```

When I run it I get the following error: `Error: Unexpected server response: 403` which basically means that server rejected handshake request. However, If I execute the same block of code in Chrome developer console (using WebSocket browser API) - I get no error and connection establishes successfully. The problem isn't with cookies and autorization headers because they're being sent after connection is established.
What am I missing here? How to make it work?

Thanks for you attention!

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to generate the websocket key randomly each time?  It's not provided to you during the handshake?

Comment: I tried removing it, still didn't work. There's no difference whether you generate it by yourself or it's generated automatically, the algorithm is the same

Comment: Probably the devtools edits/corrects your request somehow. Try to simplify it - remove extensions, laguages, cache-controls. Also consider adding the **Host** header. Probably **Host** and **Origin** must point to the same site as in _wss_ address.

Comment: Tried almost every possible headers combination, didn't work for me. Handshake with headers you suggested also fails

Answer (score 0):

Probably you miss a coockie.

`$ curl -I https://www.dextools.io
HTTP/2 403
date: Fri, 12 Jan 2024 13:39:28 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
{skipped}
referrer-policy: same-origin
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
{skipped}
set-cookie: __cf_bm=jiZr1.iD14zSdlq3TDmxUQvZTxH2JTOsuKr9STDjnq8-1705066768-1-Ac4Klcp8MicpEYiED2SRMIZD8esaChu3QnUpz06Ko0tihhUGrWQ2W+nTzwRz9Jlyc/SEXl31IxjDVXshcexX+dw=; path=/; expires=Fri, 12-Jan-24 14:09:28 GMT; domain=.dextools.io; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
{skipped}`

Comment: Thanks, but cookies won't help. The thing is, if you open Chrome Incognito window (which obviously doesn't have any cookies) and try to establish a connection - you'll succeed, so cookies have nothing to do with it

Comment: The site is behind cloudflare. 403 is given by cloudflare, not the site. The reason is most likely "bot-protection" by [Browser Integrity Check](https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/tools/browser-integrity-check/)

Comment: Yes, you're right, this site is under cloudflare protection and cloudflare itself blocks a handshake request. My question is, how can it distinguish my handshake request from the one that browser sends? Headers I send are identical. There are no cookies or auth tokens required, so what's wrong then?